# PHP: парсинг php кода

Tags: api, php, парсер

Здравствуйте! Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли в PHP какие нибудь инструменты для парсинга исходного кода? К примеру:

```
function my_function_name(){
$data_1 = array(0 => 'foo', 2 => 'bar');
$data_2 = array(0 => 'foofoo', 2 => 'barbar');
}

$src = php_load_function_src_code('my_function_name');
```

В итоге в переменной $src должен появиться исходный код функции:

```
$data_1 = array(0 => 'foo', 2 => 'bar');

$data_2 = array(0 => 'foofoo', 2 => 'barbar');
```

Или может есть какой нибудь инструментарий для реализации такого парсинга?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант - использовать рефлексию:

```
$func = new ReflectionFunction('myfunction');
$filename = $func->getFileName();
$start_line = $func->getStartLine() - 1;
$end_line = $func->getEndLine();
$length = $end_line - $start_line;

$source = file($filename);
$body = implode("", array_slice($source, $start_line, $length));
print_r($body);
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026690/reconstruct-get-code-of-php-function

Comment: Немного громоздковато, но для моих целей как раз! Спасибо!

Comment: Оберни все в функцию и не будет громоздко :)